# Python - converting a string object into a ctypes (unsigned char *)

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to use a DLL file with a function that has the following signature -

```
bool isValid = isImageValid((unsigned char *) buff, const __uint32& buffLen, 
                            int imageW, int imageH, __uint32 requiredSize);
```

Now, buff has to result from a string I'm getting to the python wrapper that is equaivalent to

```
pyBuff = open(someimagefile, 'rb').read()
```

Since pyBuff is big (mostly), I don't want to allocate a new c uchar array and copy, but to make use of the original buffer. Basically, grab the char buffer of the pyBuff object and reference it as a ctypes (c_ubyte *).

The closest I came to it is:

```
buff = cast(pyBuff, POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

But I'm not sure this is the type I want. Anyway, the function gives me the following error

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000
```

Will be glad for any help..

Also - two short questions:

1. Is the following a right definition,given that in an existing C wrapper to this DLL (which I'm working with as a reference) the function that calls (also) this one has the signature: `(const char * buff, const __uint32& buffLen)`

   ```
   byref(c_ulong(len(pyBuff))
   ```
2. What's the difference between CDLL and WinDLL, and which is the right one to use?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: 2.5. Have to work with this version

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is the Python string and you're sure `isImageValid` won't modify its contents, then you can just declare the `buff` argument as type `c_char_p`. The buffer contents won't be copied.

The `_type_` code of `c_char_p` is 'z'. In the 2.5.4 source for the setter function, [_ctypes/cfield.c : z_set](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a0a6d9909312/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1301), you see that for an `str` object it simply uses the underlying `ob_sval` pointer:

```
1309    if (PyString_Check(value)) {
1310        *(char **)ptr = PyString_AS_STRING(value);
1311        Py_INCREF(value);
1312        return value;
```

where the macro is defined as follows:

```
#define PyString_AS_STRING(op) (((PyStringObject *)(op))->ob_sval)
```

That said, if you can read the source file, you may prefer to read it into a mutable buffer. Here's how to read the contents into a ctypes `c_char` array (tested in 2.5.4):

Create a test file to be read:

```
>>> open('tmp.txt', 'w').write('''\
... This is a test.''')
```

Get the file size in a `c_uint32`, create the buffer, and read in the file contents:

```
>>> import os
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> buffLen = c_uint32()
>>> buffLen.value = os.path.getsize('tmp.txt')
>>> buff = (c_char * buffLen.value)()
>>> open('tmp.txt').readinto(buf)
15
>>> buff.value
'This is a test.'
```

Regarding your two other questions, I'd set up the function prototype like this:

```
lib = CDLL(path_to_dll)
isImageValid = lib.isImageValid
isImageValid.argtypes = c_char_p, POINTER(c_uint32), c_int, c_int, c_uint32
isImageValid.restype = c_bool
```

ctypes will automatically pass `buffLen` by reference given the above `argtypes` definition. You can also explicitly use `byref(buffLen)`.

`CDLL` is for the cdecl (C declaration) calling convention, in which the *caller* cleans up the stack. This allows variadic functions such as `printf`. `WinDLL` is for the stdcall convention, in which the *callee* cleans up the stack. stdcall is mostly used by the 32-bit Win32 API, such as Kernel32 functions. See the Wikipedia article on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I might wasn't clear about that, but I don't have access to the file itself, only to a string object after it was read. Do I have to create the C array and copy, or can I use the buffer already allocated for the Py string? For everything else, thanks a lot.

Comment: @UriElias: I revised my answer with additional information about how `c_char_p` works. I hope it helps.