# SWIG C/python and unsigned char pointers

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I have a function in the form

```
void f(unsigned char *out, const unsigned long long outlen,
       const unsigned char *in, const unsigned long long inlen);
```

and when I try to use it:

```
data_in = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
data_out = [0]*100
f(data_out, len(data_out), data_in, len(data_in))
```

(In fact, I would like to pass bytearrays)

I get something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx/basic_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    f(data_out, len(data_out), data_in, len(data_in))
TypeError: in method 'f', argument 1 of type 'unsigned char *'
```

I have tried different ways of passing data_out (encoding, byterray, [0]*100, etc.) But nothing seems to work...

How should this work?

Just in case, this might have some effect, this is a C function so to avoid mangling I am wrapping it with

```
extern "C"
{
...
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot make changes to the c code

Comment: Try to use `ctypes`, allocate an array and pass by reference.

Comment: C != C++. Please make sure to tag with the actual language you're using (which presumably is C).

Comment: It is legacy code embedded in C++ 11 application. The compiler is C++ (mangling, etc) and that is the reason I clarify about the extern "C" because it does change the signature of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers.

I know how to use ctypes but my question was about SWIG as I plan to generate wrappers for other languages too.

There is legacy code (C-like) that cannot be modified but it is part of a bigger C++11 library. This means that I may find mangling issues, etc. I prefer not to modify the signature of the functions I am exposing. The reason they are `unsigned char*` is because this is raw data. Not the typical zero terminated `char*` strings. (You could get a hint of that by looking at the `unsigned`)

The clean solution I went for was, given a function

```
bool foo(unsigned char* data)
{
   ...
}
```

Write a C++ wrapper (in some cases I used template-based tricks)

```
bool bar(vector<unsigned char> &x)
{
   foo(x.data())
}
```

in the interface file I did

```
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
  %template(ucharVector) vector<unsigned char>;
}
... include library, etc...
```

and Python:

```
data = lib.ucharVector([1, 2, 3, 4])
answer = lib.bar(data)
```

Note: With respect to const correctness, I am avoiding that in this answer to keep things simple. But it should be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your python string appears to be incompatible with the expected parameter type for the C function.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333955/python-converting-a-string-object-into-a-ctypes-unsigned-char) might help you.  It suggests using c_char_p to get the right type.  That is if you want to do it without copying the string, with some constraints.

If you can define the string however you want, or copy it, there are ctypes, of which one is `c_ubyte`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `unsigned char data[]` instead.

If you are using C++, try passing in through String class in STL.